# GCP BigQuery how to set expiration date to table by python api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-python-api

I am using BigQuery Python API to create table, and would like to set an expiration date to the table, so the table would be automatically dropped after certain days.

Here is my code:

```
client = bq.Client()
job_config = bq.QueryJobConfig()
dataset_id = dataset
table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(filename)
job_config.destination = table_ref
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=259200)
unixtime = (dt - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
expiration_time = unixtime
job_config.expires = expiration_time
query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
query_job.result()
```

The problem is that the expiration parameter doesn't seem to work.  When I am checking the table detail in the UI, the expiration date is still Never.

Answer (score 5):

To update an existing table expiration time with Python:

```py
import datetime
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
table = client.get_table("project.dataset.table")
table.expires = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
client.update_table(table, ['expires'])
```

Credits: /u/[ApproximateIdentity](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/fgataa/how_to_update_expiration_of_a_table_using_the/fk46dzo/)

Comment: Whenever I try this, it has the effect of deleting the table.  Any idea why?  (Also posted this as new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447517/updating-bigquery-table-properties-from-python-makes-table-disappear.)

Answer (score 4):

To answer a slightly different question, instead of specifying the expiration as part of the request options, you can use a [`CREATE TABLE` statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#create_table_statement) instead, where the relevant option is `expiration_timestamp`. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE my_dataset.MyTable
(
  x INT64,
  y FLOAT64
)
OPTIONS (
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
);
```

This creates a table with two columns that will expire three days from now. `CREATE TABLE` supports an optional `AS SELECT` clause, too, if you want to create the table from the result of a query (the documentation goes into more detail).

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) for the `query` method we can see that it's not possible to set an expiration time in the query job config.

The proper way of doing so is setting at the Table resource, something like:

```
client = bq.Client()
job_config = bq.QueryJobConfig()
dataset_id = dataset
table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(filename)
table = bq.Table(table_ref)
dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=259200)
table.expires = dt
client.create_table(table)

query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
query_job.result()
```

Comment: It works by adding the expiration, however, the table comes out blank.  I also tried to create the table first, then overwrite query in the table, it just a blank table with 0 B no schema either.

Comment: probably if you overwrite the table in the query operation you'll lose the expiration setting indeed. As the table is already set to be deleted, maybe overwriting it is not necessary.