# How to set existing table expiration via Python Client Library for Google BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Using the official [Python Client for Google BigQuery](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html) there doesn't appear to be a way to set the table `expires` (or other properties) on an *existing* table; you can only [create a table with the properties you want and then load data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681040/gcp-bigquery-how-to-set-expiration-date-to-table-by-python-api) "on top" of it.

The API itself has a [tables/patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch) command which does allow setting the `expirationTime` propery. However, I don't see any use of this in the client library code.

The following code in `client.py` is used for `create_table` and I *think* that simply changing `"POST"` to `"PATCH"` and adding the `table_id` to the path could work.

Is there a reason why table patching isn't supported in the client library or am I missing something?

```
    table = _table_arg_to_table(table, default_project=self.project)

    path = "/projects/%s/datasets/%s/tables" % (table.project, table.dataset_id)
    data = table.to_api_repr()
    try:
        api_response = self._call_api(retry, method="POST", path=path, data=data)
        return Table.from_api_repr(api_response)
    except google.api_core.exceptions.Conflict:
        if not exists_ok:
            raise
        return self.get_table(table.reference, retry=retry)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`client.Client` has an `update_table` method: [api reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.update_table) and [github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/bigquery-1.23.1/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L711).

You can retrieve the table settings with [`get_table`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.get_table) to get the `table.Table` [representation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table). Then, you modify the `expires` attribute with the new desired date and update it with `update_table` (note that we specify the list of fields to update):

```py
table_info = client.get_table(table_name)

table_info.expires = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
new_table_info = client.update_table(
    table_info, ['expires'])
```

As an example I create an empty table without expiration:

```sh
$ bq mk -t test.expiration
Table 'PROJECT_ID:test.expiration' successfully created.
```

and run the script (library version is `google-cloud-bigquery==1.23.1`):

```py
Initial expiration: None
Final expiration: 2019-12-22 08:47:52.507000+00:00
```

Full code:

```py
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta 

from google.cloud import bigquery

project_id = "PROJECT_ID"
table_name = "test.expiration"

client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

# get the initial expiration date
table_info = client.get_table(table_name)
print("Initial expiration: {}".format(table_info.expires))

# update with the new desired field
table_info.expires = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
new_table_info = client.update_table(
    table_info, ['expires'])

# check results
print("Final expiration: {}".format(new_table_info.expires))
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew there must be some way to work this in the current client. That method seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: When I try this, the update has the effect of simply making the table disappear.  Any idea why?  Also posted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447517/updating-bigquery-table-properties-from-python-makes-table-disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write a `patch_table()` function that utilizes the current `client` object. The potential problem here is that it will break if any the `_call_api` function name changes:

```
def patch_table(client, table, expires):
    """ Support table patching similar to `create_table`

    RE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431486/
    RE: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch

    :param client: `google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client` object.
    :param table: `google.cloud.bigquery.Table` object.
    :param expires: New expiration to apply to table.
    """
    from google.cloud.bigquery import Table
    from google.cloud.bigquery.retry import DEFAULT_RETRY

    assert isinstance(table, Table)
    table.expires = expires

    # table.description and table.labels can also be set here

    path = f"/projects/{bq.project}/datasets/{dataset}/tables/{table}"
    data = table.to_api_repr()
    api_response = client._call_api(
        DEFAULT_RETRY, method="PATCH", path=path, data=data)
    return Table.from_api_repr(api_response)
```

Hopefully this helps some others out. Perhaps it can be added to  https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py