# Updating BigQuery table properties from Python makes table disappear

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Subject pretty much says it all.  When I run the code from the BigQuery docs to change the table property (in this case, its expiration date), it seems to just summarily delete the table instead.  (Can't be found in the BQ GUI either.)  Anyone know why?  Thanks.

```
# Replace "dk" with your own initials before running this
s_table_id = 'hcwisdom.temp_tables.new_test_table'
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("full_name", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("age", "INTEGER", mode="REQUIRED"),
]
try:
    client.get_table(s_table_id)  # Make an API request.
    print("Table {} exists.".format(s_table_id))
except:
    print("Creating table {}.".format(s_table_id))
    table = bigquery.Table(s_table_id, schema=schema)
    table = client.create_table(table)
# Verify
table = client.get_table(s_table_id)
print(
    "Found {} rows and {} columns in {}".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema), s_table_id
    )
)
# Update table property
#   in the manner of https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-update-table-expiration
import datetime
table = client.get_table(s_table_id)
table.expires = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours = 2)
client.update_table(table, ['expires'])
# Try to access the table -- you'll get a "not found" error
table = client.get_table(s_table_id)
```

Comment: you are setting to expire table in two hours - so might be timezone related. to check this "theory" try to set 24 hours for example and see if issue still exists

Comment: You are quite correct -- great catch!  Happy to designate this as the accepted answer if you'd like to post it.

Comment: sure. thank you for confirming. moving to answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting to expire table in two hours - so might be timezone related. to check this "theory" try to set 24 hours for example and see if issue still exists

Comment: In addition to being correct, this drew my attention to the time-zone controlling feature of https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-update-table-expiration that I had ignored:
///////////////
import pytz ///////////////// 
table.expires = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc) + datetime.timedelta(hours = 2)